# Как передать во всплывающее окно путь к картинке и содержимое тега

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно в модальное окно передать путь к картинке, и размер, подскажите как это реализовать?
Есть размеры:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buys").click(function() {
    $(".buys").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    return false;
    });
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    if ($(".size-category").hasClass("active")) {
      document.getElementById("myImage").src=;
    }
  });
  $(".size-category").click(function() {
    $(".size-category").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    return false;
  });
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    if ($(".size-category").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".size").html("Размер: " + document.getElementsByClassName('size-category active'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="catalog-category-size">
<li class="size-category" data-id="2"><a href="#">S</a></li>
<li class="size-category" data-id="3"><a href="#">M</a></li>
<li class="size-category" data-id="4"><a href="#">L</a></li>
<li class="size-category" data-id="5"><a href="#">XL</a></li>
<li class="size-category" data-id="6"><a href="#">XXL</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="catalog__item">
                        <div class="img-catalog-block-item" style="background: url(img/red.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
                             <div class="sale"><span>-50%</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px">Товаров осталось: 9</p>
                        <div class="product-info clearfix">
                            <h5 id="prod">Товар</h5>

                        </div>
                        <div class="product-desc">
                                            </div>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="buy buys">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
                    </div>

<!-- Модальное окно -->  
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="">
        <p class="size"></p>
        <center>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="name" required="" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;margin: 10px;padding: 10px;width: 250px;">
            <input type="phone" name="phone" required="" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;margin: 10px;padding: 10px;width: 250px;">
        </form>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация плагина вам поможет:
[Страница плагина magnific-popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#options)

В частности так:

```
$('.image-link').magnificPopup({
  preloader: true,

  callbacks: {
    open: function() {
      //Сюда вставляете то, что хотите добавить в открывающееся окно
    },
    close: function() {
      //Тут можно удалить, при закрытии окна
    }
  }
});
```

или так:

```
$('.image-link').on('mfpOpen', function(e /*, params */) {
  console.log('Popup opened',  $.magnificPopup.instance);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buys').magnificPopup({
    preloader: true,
    callbacks: {
      open: function() {
        if ($(".size-category").hasClass("active")) {
          //document.getElementById("myImage").src = "";
          $(".size").html("Размер: " + $(".size-category.active a").text());
        }
      },
      close: function() {
      }
    }
  });

  $(".size-category").click(function() {
    $(".size-category").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

```css
p.size {
  background: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>


<ul class="catalog-category-size">
  <li class="size-category" data-id="2"><a href="#">S</a></li>
  <li class="size-category" data-id="3"><a href="#">M</a></li>
  <li class="size-category" data-id="4"><a href="#">L</a></li>
  <li class="size-category" data-id="5"><a href="#">XL</a></li>
  <li class="size-category" data-id="6"><a href="#">XXL</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="catalog__item">
  <div class="img-catalog-block-item" style="background: url(img/red.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
    <div class="sale"><span>-50%</span></div>
  </div>
  <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px">Товаров осталось: 9</p>
  <div class="product-info clearfix">
    <h5 id="prod">Товар</h5>

  </div>
  <div class="product-desc">
  </div>
  <a data-toggle="modal" class="buy buys" href="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
</div>

<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="" id="myImg">
        <p class="size"></p>
        <center>
          <form>
            <input type="text" name="name" required="" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;margin: 10px;padding: 10px;width: 250px;">
            <input type="phone" name="phone" required="" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;margin: 10px;padding: 10px;width: 250px;">
          </form>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```